# How to show a checked items as checked in Edit mode using a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

I am unable to get one of the business logic in my application.
Can anyone please help me out and I'm new to android development.

Btw I'm using android recyclerview for showing list of items, and I need to show the already checked items are has marked as check-in recyclerview.

I'm getting checked items from server :
InterestsList:["Antiques-Collecting","Arts-Crafts","Boating"]

These items need to compare with my recyclerView ArrayList or Items if these items are available in recyclerview I need to show as checked the item.

how can I write simple logic for this?

strings ArrayList having the Recycler items list data, InterestsList is the checked items list data.

**Here is my adapter class :**

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvInterestName.setText(interests.get(position).getInterest().toString());

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(interests.size());
        for (Interest object : interests) {
            strings.add(Objects.toString(object, null));
        }

        interestList = model.getInterests();

        System.out.println("LISTTTTTT @@@"+strings.toString());
        System.out.println("LISTTTTTT @@@"+interestList.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < interestList.size(); j++) {
                if(strings.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(interestList.get(j))) {
                    holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                }
                else
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }



        //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(interests.get(position).isSelected());

        holder.cell.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            holder.checkBox.performClick();
        });

        if (interests.get(position).isSelected()) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) ->
        {
            guestListener.OnMultipleGuestListener(position, isChecked);
        });

    }
```

Multiple Select items Interface listener used in my activity class:

```
  @Override
    public void OnMultipleGuestListener(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        interestList.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
        interestsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Required Screen change :
[image: Those 3 items are need to be checked when i enter this adapter class]

Comment: There seems some confusion here. Please confirm few things.  "interests" is List<Interest> where Interest is object (1st line in onBindViewHolder) and list is list of all interests while model.getInterests is List<String> of selected interests. right??
If yes, what mean by 1st line of OnMultipleGuestListener interface

Comment: Interests is the List<Interest> which is having all/total interests items in adapter class .
interestList in   1st line of OnMultipleGuestListener interface is the new array list of selected items i'v saved into this list and send to my server..it is added based on the position whichever i selected from recycler items that will added to list.

Answer (score 0):

As you are also capturing event when usr click on other area, lets focus on that only and ignore click on checkbox.

In xml file, make checkbox as clickable=false

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder  holder, int position) {
        String interest = interests.get(position).getInterest().toString();
        holder.tvInterestName.setText(interest);

        interestList = model.getInterests(); //assuming it's list of string from your code

        //do not assign list from model here, instead do it on separate function 
        //of adapter because we do not need to resign same list every time to 
        //interestList from some other model which have nothing to do with each 
        //item. as this method will be called for each item

        final boolean isCheck = interestList.contain(interest);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(isCheck);

        holder.cell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isChecked = !holder.checkBox.isChecked();
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(isChecked );
                guestListener.OnMultipleGuestListener(position, isChecked);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i'm using multi selection through multiselection interface.so this code won't allow me to select multipe items from recyclerview.

Comment: Why? If you are using recyclerview.selection, where is tracker. the code i have written is just optimized version. Let me know so i can help. (y)

Comment: this is only showing the checked list, but again i want to select the other items and save my edited list.

Comment: @LaxmanLucky - it will work for that also. In guestListener, you will receive checkchange event, as we have set clickListener on cell layout.

Comment: I'm using below interface for select multiple items from recyclerview items:  
@Override
    public void OnMultipleGuestListener(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        interestList.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
        interestsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: Please see my updated code once and i'm not able to save the already checked items to new array.